# SELECT with comparison operator, based on an order, skipping row(s)

Tags: mariadb, sql-order-by

I have a resultset from a `SELECT` query, based on a certain `ORDER BY` condition, and I’m trying to check the integrity of the order in which the resultset is rendered. First, I’m specifying a `LIMIT`, on the basis of which, the resultset size is limited. Then, I’m selecting a random `PK` value from the resultset, get a particular row and use the comparison operator on that row value(s), for the next `SELECT`. Something like this(Let’s suppose **a** is the random row from above):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl where tbl_columnX > a.fieldX and tbl_columnY > a.fieldY
ORDER BY certain fields
```

Basically, what I’m trying to do here, is to ensure that for a resultset (**R**) of certain order, when choosing a random **PK** value, and issuing a `SELECT` statement with comparison operator(s) on that **PK** based row value(s), the resulting set(**S**) contains the rows that are in **R**, after/before the **PK**, depending whether the order is ascending or descending.

It is basically working, except for a few cases where the next row(s) after the PK based row, have the same value(s) as the PK based row, in a few column(s). For example, these are the last few rows, from the resultset R:

```
ID(varchar)     VALUE(varchar)  DESC1(text)     DESC2(text)     NAME(text)
-------------   -------------   -------------   -------------   -------------
62E212AF            C09A        F/T/K              AH            AN
CAFFA217            C09AA       F/T/K 2            Ah            An
D90222CC            C09BA       F/T/K 2d           Ahod          Anod
```

Now, if I try to get a new resultset(S) after the `ID 62E212AF`, it skips the `ID CAFFA217`, and the first ID in the resultset is `D90222CC`. The similar pattern is repeated in a few other places. This is how I’m doing the order by, in this particular case:

```
order by 
  NAME asc,
  VALUE asc,      
  DESC1 asc, 
  DESC2 asc, 
  ID asc
```

I’d really appreciate some help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a.X > b.X AND a.Y > b.Y
```

does not correctly check for a 2-part ordering.  Instead:

```
a.X > b.X OR (a.X = b.X AND a.Y > b.Y)
```

Alternatively:

```
a.X >= b.X AND (a.X > b.X OR a.Y > b.Y)
```

"Row constructors" also work, but it may not be optimized well:

```
(a.X, a.Y) > (b.X, b.Y)
```

`ORDER BY` does the 'right thing'.

Comment: How can I do the comparison with multiple fields, in different sort order? For eg., `X ASC`, `Y DESC`, `Z DESC` and `W ASC`.

Comment: @RoshanUpreti - Mixing directions (ASC & DESC) is probably "wrong".  Going beyond two items gets quite messy, but possible.  (I don't have experience in doing so.)  If performance is not an issue, simply use a row constructor.